# Lemon tree getting malformed leaves

Tags: leaves, lemons

My meyer lemon tree is getting malformed leaves on all new sprouts. It's a 4-year old tree growing in the container. It bears about 10 lemons and they are healthy.

Any idea how it happens? Thank you all in advance!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problems on my Meyer lemon tree. The deformities are caused by the Asian citrus psyllid. They are little grey bugs that suck on the new leaves. Whenever the bug feeds, it releases a toxin that causes the leave to curl. You can read more about them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaphorina_citri).

The easiest way to get rid of them is to either hand pick them off or use an insecticide, depending on the size of the infestation. They won't kill your plant, but they can spread some bad diseases, like the citrus greening disease. So make sure to get them off your tree!

Comment: Thank you. I’ll spray some neem oil and caster oil solution to see if I can get rid of them. Will update later.